# Large file CSV transpose takes forever in C#

Tags: c#, python, csv, transpose

I'm trying to transpose a large data file that may have many rows and columns, for subsequent analysis in Excel.  Currently rows might contain either 2 or 125,000 points, but I'm trying to be generic.  (I need to transpose because Excel can't handle that many columns, but is fine if the large sets span many rows.)

Initially, I implemented this is Python, using the built-in zip function.  I process the source file to separate long rows from short, then transpose the long rows with zip:

```
tempdata = zip(*csv.reader(open(tempdatafile,'r')))
csv.writer(open(outfile, 'a', newline='')).writerows(tempdata)
os.remove(tempdatafile)
```

This works great and takes a few seconds for a 15MB csv file, but since the program that generated the data in the first place is in C#, I thought it would be best to do it all in one program.

My initial approach in C# is a little different, since from what I've read, the zip function might not work quite the same.  Here's my approach:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    StreamReader source;
    int Rows = 0;
    int Columns = 0;
    string filePath = "input.csv";
    string outpath = "output.csv";

    List<string[]> test_csv = new List<string[]>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        source = new StreamReader(filePath);

        while(!source.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] Line = source.ReadLine().Split(',');
            test_csv.Add(Line);
            if (test_csv[Rows].Length > Columns) Columns = test_csv[Rows].Length;
            Rows++;
        }
    }

    private void button_Write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(outpath);

        for (int i = 0; i < Columns; i++)
        {
            string line = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < Rows; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (j != 0) line += ",";
                    line += test_csv[j][i];
                }
                catch { }
            }
            outfile.WriteLine(line);
        }
        outfile.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Outfile written");
    }
}
```

I used the `List` because the rows might be of variable length, and I have the load function set to give me total number of columns and rows so I can know how big the outfile has to be.

I used a `try/catch` when writing to deal with variable length rows.  If the indices are out of range for the row, this catches the exception and just skips it (the next loop writes a comma before an exception occurs).

Loading takes very little time, but actually *saving* the outfile is an insanely long process. After 2 hours, I was only 1/3 of the way through the file.  When I stopped the program and looked at the outfile, everything is done correctly, though.

What might be causing this program to take so long?  Is it all the exception handling?  I could implement a second `List` that stores row lengths for each row so I can avoid exceptions.  Would that fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try using `StringBuilder`.  Concatenation (`+`) of long strings is very inefficient.
- Create a `List<string>` of lines and then make a single call `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, lines)`.  This will reduce disk IO.
- If you don't care about the order of the points try changing your outside for loop to `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For`.  This will run multiple threads.  Since these run parallel it won't preserve the order when writing it out.

In regards to your exception handling:  Since this is an error that you can determine ahead of time, you should not use a `try/catch` to take care of it.  Change it to this:

```
if (j < test_csv.Length && i < test_csv[j].Length)
{
  line += test_csv[j][i];
}
```

Comment: So in the end, it was all the exception handling that did it. I did end up using `StringBuilder` but that didn't change anything.  Replacing the `try/catch` with that `if` statement brought the time down to less than a second!  Good `catch`!